# How to break out of python input when VLC audio player ends?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, while-loop, vlc

I am trying to make a music-playing program in Python3 using `python-vlc` to play audio files. I want to be able to pause and play the audio as long as the song is not over. I have a `playSong(path)` function which plays an audio file from a given path, and a `main` method which calls the `playAudio` function on whatever song path I specify. I also have a few other functions for downloading songs from YouTube using `youtube-dl`. There *are no problems* with the `main` or any of the other methods. The issue is in the `playSong` function.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import random
import vlc
import ytUrl
import youtube_dl
from termcolor import colored
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

...

def playSong(path):
    audio = MP3(path)
    duration = audio.info.length  # This is not in use as of right now
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(path)
    player.audio_set_delay(1000)  # keeps vlc from playback freezing issues
    player.play()
    print("Playing " + colored(path[:-len(".mp3")], "green") + "...")

    # the problem is here
    while True:
        do = input("> ").lower()
        if do == "pause":
            player.pause()
        elif do == "play":
            player.play()
        elif do == "stop" or do == "skip":
            player.stop()
        elif do == "exit":
            player.stop()
            main()
```

The problem is that the `playSong` method will not exit when the `player` finishes the song because of the `while True` loop. The program is stuck on

```
do = input("> ").lower()
```

even when the player has finished. I can't just take out the `while` loop becuase I want to be able to play and pause the song the whole time!

How should I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on Ubuntu. I believe it will also work on Mac but not on Windows:

```py
import os
import re
import selectors
import sys
import random
import vlc
import ytUrl
import youtube_dl
from termcolor import colored
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

...

def playSong(path):
    audio = MP3(path)
    duration = audio.info.length  # This is not in use as of right now
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer(path)
    player.audio_set_delay(1000)  # keeps vlc from playback freezing issues
    player.play()
    print("Playing " + colored(path[:-len(".mp3")], "green") + "...")

    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
    sel.register(sys.stdin.fileno(), selectors.EVENT_READ)

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write('> ')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        # Poll for command input as long as the player hasn't reached the end
        while player.get_state() != vlc.State.Ended:
            if sel.select(0.1):
                break  # Input avaliable - time to read input, so stop polling
        else:
            break  # Quit the command handling loop
        do = input().lower()
        if do == "pause":
            player.pause()
        elif do == "play":
            player.play()
        elif do == "stop" or do == "skip":
            player.stop()
        elif do == "exit":
            player.stop()
            main()
```

Comment: Maybe the `player.get_length() == 0 or player.get_time() < player.get_length()` condition isn't a reliable test for the player reaching the end of the song. I'm not familiar with python-vlc. Maybe you can test for a specific end-of-media event somehow with that API?

Comment: Works for me on my Mac! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Swap `while True:` with `while player.is_playing == 1:`, thus exiting loop when song ends.